# Send email reminder after 3 month

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron

I have a database and a website where registered users can download 'info cards' to their smartphone.
After 3 month they have to return them to the database. I have set up a cron job that runs my php script once every 24 hours. But no email output. I have searched around for examples and tutorials, but so far no luck. 
Does anyone of you have any suggestion to what could be the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php

require_once 'includes/connect_database.php';
DatabaseConnect();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM My_table WHERE downloaded = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 3 MONTH)";
if (false === ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    trigger_error('there was a query/sql problem', E_USER_ERROR);
}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Send email to user with expired info card
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        // send email to user
        mail($row['email'], 'The email Subject', 'The email message body');

        sleep(2);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
else {
    // nothing to do today
}
```

Comment: Is the php script working if you just run it manually? It looks like you've missed out the closing " on the line beginning with `$sql = `

Comment: No, the php script is not working. I have tried with just a simple mail command in the script, and it worked.

Comment: Do you get any PHP errors or warnings when you run it manually?

Comment: shouldn't it be NOW - 3 MONTH?

Comment: I get a blank screen. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

Run script manually.
Check for php errors.
Run query manually in your database or phpmyadmin.
If you receive data, check your php script - start debugging logic of script.
If you dont see data, there is nothing to show.

**EDIT:** after you told me you tried and you get results in mysql, instead of

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
```

try to use

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
```

or

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions. I received data in a mysql query. So my php script must be the problem.